# Copying a triangular area from one picture to another in Python

Tags: python, image-manipulation

I am trying to write a python function that will copy a triangular area from anywhere on a picture to a new blank picture. I can copy a rectangular area from a picture to a new empty picture, but I just don't know how to copy a triangle. That's what I have, but it only copies a rectangular area. Sorry if it looks messy or over-complicated, but I'm just starting how to write in python.

```
  def copyTriangle():
     file=pickAFile()
     oldPic=makePicture(file)
     newPic=makeEmptyPicture(getWidth(oldPic),getHeight(oldPic))
     xstart=getWidth(oldPic)/2
     ystart=getHeight(oldPic)/2
     for y in range(ystart,getHeight(oldPic)):
         for x in range(xstart,getWidth(oldPic)):
           oldPixel=getPixel(oldPic,x,y)
           colour=getColor(oldPixel)
           newPixel=getPixel(newPic,x,y)
           setColor(newPixel,colour)
```

Answer (score 5):

Function to copy a triangular area from one pic to another.

```
def selectTriangle(pic):
  w= getWidth (pic)
  h = getHeight(pic)
  newPic = makeEmptyPicture(w,h)
  x0=107#test point 0
  y0=44
  x1=52#test point 1
  y1=177
  x2=273 #test point 2
  y2=216
#(y-y0)/(y1-y0)=(x-x0)/(x1-x0)

  for y in range (0,h):
    for x in range (0, w):
#finding pixels within the plotted lines between eat set of points
      if (x>((y-y0)*(x1-x0)/(y1-y0)+x0) and x<((y-y0)*(x2-x0)/(y2-y0)+x0) and x>((y-y2)*(x1-x2)/(y1-y2)+x2)): 
        pxl = getPixel(pic, x, y)
        newPxl= getPixel(newPic,x,y)
        color = getColor(pxl)
        setColor (newPxl, color)

  return (newPic)
```

[image: Original Image]
[image: Triangle]

Comment: +1: for a nice, fully worked out answer to a poorly stated problem.  I'm sure others will find this useful.  (Still, though, my answer is not wrong, but this is much better.)

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to do it pixel by pixel as in your example, then just copy the pixels of the triangle.  Mostly this depends on how you want to define the triangle.

The simplest triangle is to make your x range (inner loop) dependent on your y-value (outer loop), like:

```
for y in range(ystart, ystart+getHeight(oldPic)):
    for x in range(xstart, xstart + int( getWidth(oldPic)*((y-ystart)/float(getHeight)):
```

More generally, you could still keep your same x and y loops, and then put the copying commands in an `if` block, where you check whether the point is in your triangle.

Beyond this, there are much more efficient ways of doing this, using masks, etc.

Note, also here I changed the y-range to `range(ystart, ystart+getHeight(oldPic))`, which I think is probably what you want for a height that doesn't depend on the starting position.

Comment: @Yve: you're incorrect here.  if the triangle base is at `ystart=100`, and it has a height of `5`, then my answer `range(ystart, ystart+getHeight)=(100, 105)`, which is correct, and while `(ystart, getHeight)=range(100, 5)` which makes no sense.  Partly, though, this depends on definitions, and I don't know what you mean by `h`, but for `getHeight`, my original answer is correct.

Comment: @Yve: this is rediculous.  You're just effectively doing `range(0, h)` for the loop and adding `ystart` inside the loop.  If you do it for the range of the loop, it's `range(ystart, ystart+getHeight)`.  It's basically just the definition of terms, but when voting on my answer, it's reasonable to ask whether or not it's right and reasonable, not whether I'm doing `1+2` instead of `2+1`.

Comment: @Yve: OK, so it seems that you're saying that using `range(ystart+getHeight(oldPic))` is wrong, but `range(ystart+getHeight)` would be correct?  Do I have this right?  Then, what do you think is the difference between `getHeight` and `getHeight(oldPic)`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33222/discussion-between-tom10-and-yve)